# PHP mysql variable

Tags: php, mysqli

yesterday i was doing work in php mysql
i wrote a query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `first` (`firstName`, `lastName`, `address1`,  `city`, `state`, `zip`, `country`, `amount`, `date`) VALUES ('$firstName','$lastName','$address1','$city','$state','$zip','$country','$amount','$date')")
```

it did not work for me and then my boss wrote below query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `first` (`firstName`, `lastName`, `address1`,  `city`, `state`, `zip`, `country`, `amount`, `date`) VALUES ('".$firstName."','".$lastName."','".htmlentities($address1)."','".$city."','".$state."','".$zip."','".$country."','".$amount."','".$date."')");
```

and it works!!

is there anything wrong in first query..please help me out..

Comment: What was `$address1`? The only differences here is the use of `htmlentities()` in the second query.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "it did not work"?

Comment: Both are very, very wrong. You should be very afraid of SQL injection. Never insert variables this way. Check [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and use parameters

Comment: @Uriel_SVK, I think the OP's confusion here stems from the use of double quotes in PHP. While you're right that parameterized queries are generally safer, how do you know those variables are not perfectly 'cleansed' before that query is executed? People are quick to play the SQL Injection card, even when it has nothing to do with the question. I know I am bitter. Still, +1 for a good suggestion.

Comment: If there is any single quote in $address, then the query stops the execution. You can use mysql_escape_string for escaping quotes. htmlentities converts the characters to html entities, so your boss's query has executed successfully.

Answer (score 3):

First query should work, but you got probably quotes in the content of your variables. Also, always use atleast mysql_real_escape_string.
https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Or even better, use PDO
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

This function is identical to [htmlspecialchars()](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) in all ways, except with htmlentities(), all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities.